# Showing a set is satisfiable with a truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

How can it be shown with a truth table that this set is satisfiable or not satisfiable?

$$E = \{A, A\rightarrow B, A\rightarrow \neg S \}$$

Comment: Try to find a truth assignmet that works; if you find "contradictory" assignments to the same variable, this means that the set is unsat.

Comment: Try starting from $A$; obviously we must have $v(A)=\text T$.

Comment: So would it be v(A) = T must be true, v(A) =T and v(B) = T, for (A->B) to be true, and v(S) = F so that (A -> $\neg$ S) is true, to make the entire set satisfiable?

Comment: Is it possible to put them all in one truth table side by side or not possible?

Comment: Exactly; having found an assignment that satisfies all the formula, the set is satisfiable.

Comment: And yes; you can build a truth table with three columns for the three variables and three columns for the three formulas (two are enough). If you find a line where all the formulas are TRUE, it's done.

Comment: Would the column for A, be T,T,T,T ? or what would the column for A be set as?

Comment: You must write all the combinations for $A,B,S$ : 1st column TTTTFFFF 2nd column TTFFTTFF; 3rd column TFTFTFTF.

Comment: The 2nd row : TTF will satisfy all the three formulas.